# Mysql phpmyadmin show empty cardinality

Tags: mysql, indexing, phpmyadmin

Why does phpMyAdmin show an empty cardinality?
[image]

If I edit the index (without change anything) and save, the cardinality will appear, but after a TRUNCATE and some INSERTs, the cardinality become empty again.

Running

```
ALTER TABLE tableName ENABLE KEYS
```

doesn't help.

How to make the cardinality always present?

**Edit:**

The phpMyAdmin version is 4.6.4

The MySql version is libmysql - mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev - 20150407

The Engine is MyISAM

Comment: Why do you do `TRUNCATE`?  It is rarely needed.

Comment: Why do you care if the cardinality goes away?

Comment: @RickJames, because I suppose that if it's NULL, the index does not work properly to speed up the table's selects. Isn't true?

Comment: "the index does not..." -- Please show us the _query_ for which the index is misbehaving.

Comment: @RickJames, I refer to all possibile query that can be done on that table. My worry is that with an NULL index's cardinality, the selects will be slower on that fields.

Comment: I wonder if it a bug in phpmyadmin; I suspect that product gets it from the same place that `SHOW INDEXES FROM ...` gets the data, which would be the `information_schema`.  If you can find `NULLs` in either of those place, please file a bug report at bugs.mysql.com.  What version of MySQL are you using?  Which Engine?

Comment: I updated the question with those informations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [analyze the table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/analyze-table.html).

```
ANALYZE LOCAL TABLE tablename
```

The stats for the primary key are updated when the data is updated, but the other indexes need this operation to set a value. Note that if the **distribution** of the data is not changing then you don't need to refresh the indexes.

Note that there is a performance impact (and locking impact with MyISAM) on large tables when you run this.

Comment: So, I must run that every time the script ends the INSERTs? I need a definitive solution.

Comment: No. You run it when relative cardinality becomes sufficiently skewed as to force the optimizer to generate bad execution plans. (hint: its unlikely to impact the performance until you have more than a hundred times more data than shown in the above)

Comment: It works but I must run it after every data's import :-( Without other alternatives I'll do that.

Comment: The optimizer only needs a rough picture of the shape of the data - try it a few times and see if the **pattern** of the numbers changes.

Answer (score 0):

Aha -- I found NULLs with `SHOW INDEXES` on a MyISAM table.  Is yours `ENGINE=MyISAM`?  Recommend changing to InnoDB.

Comment: Any different solution? I can't change the engine.